# Jpa custom query with date nearest to present filter

Tags: sql, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I have SpringBoot webapp using JPA and I have a model class like this:

```
@Entity
class Server {
  .....
  private Date updateDate;

}
```

now I would like to create a custom query inside my repository to get the *Server* entity with the attribute *updateDate* nearest to present Date in Oracle 11g database.

Right now I found just a few example, like this for SQLServer:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM x
WHERE x.date < @CurrentDate
ORDER BY x.date DESC
```

I would like something similar to build a custom query with Jpa in Oracle 11g DB.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring Data JPA you can create a repository method:

```
Server findFirstByUpdateDateLessThan(Date currentDate);
```

You have to pass the currentDate as parameter because there is no way to use current_date in a repository method.

If you want to use a query that would be possible.

You could also use plain JPA:

```
List<Server> list = entityManager
       .createQuery("select s from Server s where s.updateDate < current_date", Server.class)
       .setMaxResults(1)
       .getResultList();
```

If you are sure that you will get one result you could also call getSingleResult()

Answer (score 0):

no, maybe I expressed myself badly. In any case, I want a method, using Jpa, that gives me back the entity whose date is more recent.

The solution is:

```
public interface ZabbixInstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<ZabbixInstance,String> {

  @Query("select z from ZabbixInstance z where z.refreshDate = (select max(z.refreshDate) from ZabbixInstance z)")
  ZabbixInstance findByClosestDate();

}
```

It works perfectly. I hope it helps others.

Thanks anyway